# How to program a bunch of 1st person animations at different speeds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made 4 different types of animation clips in an animator for an an empty gameobject called "Animator". The main camera is a child of this.
The animations feature a running cycle, a walking cycle, a crouch cycle, and an idle cycle. They all have a trigger that let's them play.
How am I able to measure the speed of the player and execute these animations when the player reaches a certain speed. I have found someone else trying to do this and it works but only for idle and walk. But unfortunately I can't get the sprint and crouch to work. I'm not sure what to do, either have the sprint and crouch animations or just change the speed of the walk animation depending on whether the player is sprinting or crouching. I'll leave a comment where the code I found is.

Here's what I have in my player controller (thge trigger stop is for the idle animation):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    Animator _ar;
    

    public float speed;
    [Range(-5, -20)]
    public float gravity = -9.81f;

    public float sprintSpeed = 6f;
    public float walkSpeed = 4f;
    public float crouchSpeed = 2f;


    public float standHeight = 1.6f;
    public float crouchHeight = 1f;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public Light _l;

    //Set this to the transform you want to check
    public Transform objectTransfom;

    private float noMovementThreshold = 0.0001f;
    private const int noMovementFrames = 1;
    Vector3[] previousLocations = new Vector3[noMovementFrames];
    public bool isMoving;

    //Let other scripts see if the object is moving
    public bool IsMoving
    {
        get { return isMoving; }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        //For good measure, set the previous locations
        for (int i = 0; i < previousLocations.Length; i++)
        {
            previousLocations[i] = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        
        _ar = GameObject.Find("Animator").GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);



        //Below here is the code I found. The if statements for isMoving, is what I put in to see if
        //this worked.

        //Store the newest vector at the end of the list of vectors
        for (int i = 0; i < previousLocations.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            previousLocations[i] = previousLocations[i + 1];
        }
        previousLocations[previousLocations.Length - 1] = objectTransfom.position;

        //Check the distances between the points in your previous locations
        //If for the past several updates, there are no movements smaller than the threshold,
        //you can most likely assume that the object is not moving
        for (int i = 0; i < previousLocations.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(previousLocations[i], previousLocations[i + 1]) >= noMovementThreshold)
            {
                //The minimum movement has been detected between frames
                isMoving = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                isMoving = false;
            }
        }

        if(isMoving == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                speed = sprintSpeed;
                _ar.SetTrigger("WalkSprint");
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            {
                speed = crouchSpeed;
                _ar.SetTrigger("WalkCrouch");
                //transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.8f, 0.5f, 0.8f);
            }
            else
            {
                speed = walkSpeed;
                _ar.SetTrigger("Walk");
                //transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.8f, 0.85f, 0.8f);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _ar.SetTrigger("Stop");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you need to change this line - else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl)) to this line - else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl)), because how your code will have understand when your player is will crouching.

Comment: That was a small mistake by me, however nothing works anymore, I can move around. But for some reason I can't sprint or crouch and the animation still keeps playing idle. Also it is no longer detecting if I am moving or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as with many issue in Game Dev, this could be a number of different issues (or all of them!).  Here is where you can start to debug:

1. Check your error log to see if there is anything obvious that jumps out at you, like a bad reference to a Game Object/Componenet.
2. Watch the animator. You should be able to have the Animator open, side-by-side with your game window while the game is running.  You should be able to see the animations running and transitioning.  See if something is not linked properly, or if an animation time is configured incorrectly, etc.
3. Add some debug statements, like outputting the current trigger being set.  I would even verify that your inputs are configured correctly.  Maybe add some additional conditionals at the beginning that debug what inputs are being pressed.
4. As @OnionFan said, your Input check is for KeyUp for the Crouch key.  That should probably be KeyDown.